# How can I read the filename correctly which contains non-ASCII characters?

Tags: powershell

A file is created in cmd.exe containing a LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA character. This is using codepage 1252 on an NTFS file system.

```
C:>echo>fileÇ.txt asdf

C:>dir fileÇ.txt
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is 1C66-809A

 Directory of C:\src\t

2020-10-15  04:44                 6 fileÇ.txt
```

When retrieving the filename in PowerShell 5.1, the character appears to be unmappable and is replaced with a QUESTION MARK character.

```
PS C:\src\t> (dir .\fileÇ.txt).Name
fileÇ.txt
PS C:\src\t> (dir .\fileÇ.txt).Name|Format-Hex


           00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000   66 69 6C 65 3F 2E 74 78 74                       file?.txt
```

Comment: Is the filename correctly set? I suppose it's a cmd, not ps problem. If the file shows up correctly on disk, it do so too in powershell. What is your `$OutputEncoding`?

Comment: Try `Format-Hex -Encoding Unicode`